# Assign different background colour to each dropdown to bootstrap nav-bar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to assign different background colour to each dropdown to bootstrap nav-bar using css.

```css
.mynavbar .dropdown ul.dropdown-menu:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #59b057;
}

.mynavbar .dropdown ul.dropdown-menu:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #eb712b;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">COMPANY</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right scrollable-menu">
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DOWNLOAD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CERTIFICATION</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CAREERS</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">FACILITIES</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right scrollable-menu">
    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTION</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">R&amp;D</a></li>

  </ul>
</li>
```

All these dropdown should have different background colours.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. You can use "classes" (add class to each dropdown) and color it via class selector. Or you can use pseudo attributes `:first-child`, `:nth-child(number)` or `:nth-child(odd)` to select it and color.

Comment: yes, i have tried same but it didn't work... dropdown-menu class has a property of background-colour..so i could not change to every dropdown's background colour.

Comment: Do you place your styles after or before the bootstrap styles? (the last styles overrides all styles which has been placed before).

Comment: Sorry i don't have idea about so i didn't place. please, can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a colour to the list with the class **"greentbg"** you must define CSS attributes for that class. To override the default bootstrap CSS, you must append **"!important"** to the attribute to ensure that it is applied.

```
.greentbg {
     background-color: green !important;
}
```

I have created an example based on the code you have provided:
https://jsfiddle.net/fxjrp1n7/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use ID's. Give each dropdown-menu a different ID then use css to style each separately.

```
<ul id="backgroundcolor1" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right scrollable-menu">

#backgroundcolor1,
#backgroundcolor1:hover,
#backgroundcolor1:active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Also remember to "empty cache and hard reload" after you make changes to the CSS files so they will take affect on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with li and a?
Not sure...

```
.mynavbar .dropdown li.dropdown-menu:nth-child(1) a {    background: red; }
.mynavbar .dropdown li.dropdown-menu:nth-child(2) a {    background: yellow; }
```